# Django REST Framework consolidate response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using the Django REST Framework and in a single response want to return an array object along with a "consolidated" object. The "consolidated" object will be populated at runtime by adding each item's property values together.

This response data illustrates what I'm looking for.

```
{
    "foods": [
        {
            "name": "Apple",
            "calories": 116,
            "sugars": 23.2
        },
        {
            "name": "Orange",
            "calories": 62,
            "sugars": 12.2
        }
    ],
    "consolodated": {
        "calories": 178,
        "sugars": 35.4
    }
}
```

Returning the "foods" array is straight forward but I don't know how to create the "consolidated" object at runtime.  Since I'm not serializing a model should this dynamic object creation sit in the view?  If so what approach do I take to iterate over the existing values to create a new object? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into the `pre_save()` methods? you could serialize your food object then on `pre_save()` set the `serializer.data[consolidated] = {"calories": 178,"sugars": 35.4}`

Comment: Thanks but for now I'm creating "consolidated" at runtime. If I want to store it in the future I'll consider using pre_save()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want a [Doc link: "Serializer Method Field"](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields.html#serializermethodfield)
which will let you make a field out of a method that provides that "consolidated" element.